# Rendering Teams channel messages as cards

Tags: javascript, html, adaptive-cards, microsoft-graph-sdks, microsoft-graph-teams

I am developing a frontend application using Angular that should show conversations in Teams channels. Currently I'm a little bit lost when it comes to showing chat messages. I understand that Teams makes use of AdaptiveCards to display different types of messages, like 'vnd.microsoft.card.thumbnail', and that one should use AdaptiveCards for rendering cards to HTML instead of doing all of the work to manually create all sorts of HTML templates.

But this is exactly what I am failing at :(

This basic example works just fine: https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/adaptive-cards/sdk/rendering-cards/javascript/render-a-card
But as soon as I am trying to render a card with the data I receive from the Microsoft Graph API ('/teams/{tid}/channels/{cid}/messages'), it just shows nothing. It seems as if the data doesn't fit together. For example, AdaptiveCards have a property called 'actions' whereas Graph's chatMessage objects have 'buttons'.

What am I missing?

Thanks a lot,
Bruno

Comment: You need to make sure that the template you are using matches the data, easiest is take a copy of the JSON payload you receive put that in the designer or vscode and edit your template to match the actual data you receive. However im not 100% sure if this would work without any hacks on your end. No idea what you receive from Graph API right now. 

On a different note, MS Teams is not using Adaptive Cards to render normal conversation messages, this is just used for Bot messages, interactive stuff and apps.

Comment: Yes, the normal messages come as text, but it's the interactive stuff that's interesting to me. I thought it would just work like this:

    var adaptiveCard = new AdaptiveCards.AdaptiveCard();
    adaptiveCard.parse(data);
    var renderedCard = adaptiveCard.render();
    document.body.appendChild(renderedCard);

Maybe contentType='application/vnd.microsoft.card.thumbnail' is the problem, because AdaptiveCards in all samples always has type='AdaptiveCard'?

Comment: Well yea but teams might do stuff which doesn't work for normal renderers , not sure 100% atm.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can attain what you want using adaptive cards. As I understand, you want the JSON result from the Microsoft Graph API ('/teams/{tid}/channels/{cid}/messages') to be rendered as Adaptive Card without any processing. This will not happen. You should parse the data and then mapp it to the adaptive card JSON values.